# Azure DevOps repository trigger not firing

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-yaml

I want pipeline for one repository to be run after a commit is made to another repository inside the same Azure project.

My pipeline definition:

```
resources:         
  repositories:
  - repository: SupDevA
    name: Sup.Dev.A
    type: git
    ref: test
    trigger:
      branches:
        include:
        - test
  
steps:
- script: 'echo test'


- template: dummy-template.yml@SupDevA
  parameters:
    text: 'testing if the dummy templates is executed'
```

Sup.Dev.A is the name of the repository that should trigger my pipeline when commit is made on branch `test`. But when I create a commit on branch test, the trigger does not fire.

Both repositories are in the same project
Am I missing something? The code was based on ms documentation https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/repos/multi-repo-checkout?view=azure-devops#triggers

EDIT:
The -template section was added so its clear that, when manually triggered, pipeline executes template from the resource repository succesfully

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since @walter-qian-msft reproduced this successfully it must be something with pipeline location that is messing with triggers.

Since he probabbly tested this on default branch, did you try merging your YAML files to `master`/`main` branches?

Comment: Thanks! It works when having the yaml definition on `master` branch. The question is why is this the case? Whats so special about master/main branch it only works on them if when creating pipeline I select, lets say `test` branch, and pick yaml definition that is on that branch

Comment: @StackNet Currently dealing with same issue. Moved a pipeline on different branch than `main` and the repository trigger is not working anymore. Were you able to resolve it?

Comment: Hi guys, were you able to resolve this issue? I'm having this right now

Comment: Is there no solution to test this on a branch other than **main/master**? spent the whole day trying to find a solution, until I found this thread

Answer (score 1):

Your sample worked well on my side.

```
# Repo: test
# File: azure-pipelines.yml
resources:         
  repositories:
  - repository: SupDevA
    name: Sup.Dev.A
    type: git
    ref: test
    trigger:
      branches:
        include:
        - test

steps:
- script: 'echo test'
- template: dummy-template.yml@SupDevA
  parameters:
    text: 'testing if the dummy templates is executed'

# Repo: Sup.Dev.A
# File: dummy-template.yml
parameters:
- name: text
  default: ''
  type: string

steps:
- script: echo ${{ parameters.text }}
```

Your yaml is correct, I suggest you can delete the repo and recreate a new one. In addition, please check if you override the CI trigger.

[image]
[image]

By the way, you can also refer to [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/templates?view=azure-devops#use-other-repositories).

Comment: Hi, thanks!
So I've tried to create 2 new repos/pipelines and it works so the problem is obviously with one of those original pipelines. I've recreated both but still it doesnt trigger. May I ask where did you find this "Triggers" UI from your screenshot beause I'm using yaml only pipelines and can't seem to find this dashboard

Comment: @StackNet I added an image in the answer, please check it.

Comment: Thanks, the checkbox is unchecked. Still trying.

Answer (score 0):

I think that `ref: test` might be confusing it.

I would try removing `ref: test`, as the trigger branch include should handle that. If it really does need to be there, I'd change it to `ref: 'refs/heads/test'`.

Comment: hi, thanks but regardless of having ref or removing it, it does not work :/ I dont see what i'm doing wrong .. I even added a "dummy" template in repository Sup.Dev.A and when I manually run the pipeline it succesfully executes template from the repository so I know the referece to repo is correct

Comment: If you trigger the build manually, does it work?

Comment: If i trigger the pipeline it runs, yes..I will edit the questions so its visible that the reference works

Comment: When I do something very similar to your example against my repos, this seems to work properly. So, the only thing now that stands out is the repository reference itself. The line `- repository: Sup.Dev.A`  is not supposed to contain periods. The Pipeline editor page in Azure DevOps flags it. Now, that said, it still works on mine, but it might be worth changing it to `SupDevA` (this is just a handle for the repo to be used in subsequent steps as needed)?

Comment: Sure I changed it so it doesnt include dots..Still no luck :/

Comment: I might try, at this point, removing the pipeline (leaving the YAML file there), and then recreating based on that YAML file. Or create a new pipeline and put the same YAML into it. At this point, I'd want to verify that something isn't messed up in the pipeline beneath the YAML?

Answer (score 0):

This is really more of a comment than an answer, so i'll delete it afterwards if this is not helpful.
This is something that works for me;

```yaml
trigger: none

resources:
  pipelines:
  - pipeline: 'HmiTpm-Ci'
    source: HmiTpm-Ci
    trigger:
      branches:
      - master
      - features/*
  - pipeline: 'HmiTpm-Release'
    source: HmiTpm-Release
    trigger:
      branches:
      - master
      - features/*
...
```

If i look at your script I don't see the `source` defined - could you try defining that?

In my case, i'm not using a template - so that may be the issue.

Comment: hi, thanks..the difference is that I use "repository" resource and you use "pipeline" resource
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/yaml-schema?view=azure-devops&tabs=schema%2Cparameter-schema#repository-resource

Comment: Ah yeah you're right.  but you stated 'I want pipeline for one repository to be run after a commit is made to another repository inside the same Azure project' and this is how that is done. This particular pipeline is declared in some repository and runs whenever  a change to repository HmiTpm-Ci is made. Is that now what you want? I may be mistaken here - its friday, i'm not that sharp atm.